# Apache Tomcat reboot. Could not load com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I use Apache Tomcat 7.0 with connection-pooling in Spring Source and Hibernate POJO's.
Always that I reboot Tomcat I have the following error:

```
03-dic-2013 9:33:46 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Acceso ilegal: esta instancia de aplicación web ya ha sido parada.  Could not load com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.  La eventual traza de pila que sigue ha sido motivada por un error lanzado con motivos de depuración así como para intentar terminar el hilo que motivó el acceso ilegal y no tiene impacto funcional.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3321)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.quit(MysqlIO.java:1667)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:4322)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.cleanup(ConnectionImpl.java:1348)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.finalize(ConnectionImpl.java:2679)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:83)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:14)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:160)
```

Do you know how I can fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Whereabouts is the `mysql-connector` jar file? Is it in Tomcat's lib folder or in your application's WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Yes. The connection works OK. The problem is when I reboot Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you closed your connection before rebooting?
If you haven't it could reach your maximum allowed connections in database settings if you keep making new connections.

```
 Connection con;
 try {
 con = ...; // open connection    
catch (SQLException e) {
// do stuff with your connection
 } finally {
 if (con != null && !con.isClosed()) {
    try {
        con.close();
    catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Failed to close connection", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to close the connection directly? But I'm closing connections sessions when I do the database queries:
`Session session = getSession();
        Instrumentos ins = null;
        try {
            Criteria consulta = session.createCriteria....;
            consulta.add(Restrictions.eq("....", ....));
            List<Instrumentos> lista = consulta.list();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
`

Comment: No need to close the connection directly. The piece of code you show however closes a session, wich has nothing to do with your database.

Standard format for getting a db connection in java: 
see post above. Note the con.close();

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I will develop this function when the spring bean will be destroyed.